# Skip Record and Move On to the Next In PowerShell ForEach Loop

Tags: powershell, foreach

I have the following PowerShell code that queries a SQL database. If the number of results from the query is not 0, for each result, the First/Only Design Number is added to the FirstOnlyDesignNumbers array. The NextDesignNumber is each FirstOnlyDesignNumber added to the application count. I then compare the results and output as JSON.

```
`[CmdletBinding()]
    param ()
try{
    $query = 'C:\Queries\MissingDesignNumbersCheck.sql'
    $SQLConnection = Invoke-Sqlcmd2 -ServerInstance $SQLInstance -Database "$Database -InputFile $query -Credential $r_sa_pd -As DataSet
    $table = $SQLConnection.Tables[0]
    $count = $table.Rows.Count
    if (-not $count -eq 0){
        $NextDesignNumbers = @()
        $FirstOnlyDesignNumbers = @()
        foreach ($row in $table.Rows){
        $FirstOnlyDesignNumbers += $row.'First/Only Design Number'
        $NextDesignNumbers += [int]$row.'First/Only Design Number' + [int]$row.'Application Count'
        }
        $compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $FirstOnlyDesignNumbers -DifferenceObject $NextDesignNumbers
        $InputObject = $compare | Where-Object SideIndicator -EQ '=>'
        $json = $InputObject.InputObject | ConvertTo-Json
        $json
}catch
    {
        Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
    }`
```

If the for loop returns a value that is a string, not an int, I need to ignore it and move on to the next item in the for loop.

Currently an exception is thrown saying that it can't handle a string and the whole function breaks.

I have tried the following but not sure if this is the best approach, or if `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` or another alternative would be better?

```
[CmdletBinding()]
    param ()
try{
    $query = 'C:\Queries\MissingDesignNumbersCheck.sql'
    $SQLConnection = Invoke-Sqlcmd2 -ServerInstance $SQLInstance -Database $Database -InputFile $query -Credential $r_sa_pd -As DataSet
    $table = $SQLConnection.Tables[0]
    $count = $table.Rows.Count
    if (-not $count -eq 0){
        $NextDesignNumbers = @()
        $FirstOnlyDesignNumbers = @()
        foreach ($row in $table.Rows){
            if($row -match "^[\d\.]+$"){
                Continue
            }
            $FirstOnlyDesignNumbers += $row.'First/Only Design Number'
            $NextDesignNumbers += [int]$row.'First/Only Design Number' + [int]$row.'Application Count'
        }
        $compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $FirstOnlyDesignNumbers -DifferenceObject $NextDesignNumbers
        $InputObject = $compare | Where-Object SideIndicator -EQ '=>'
        $json = $InputObject.InputObject | ConvertTo-Json
        $json
        }
}catch
    {
        Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
    }
```

Comment: Note that applying `-match` to `$row` won't work meaningfully, because `[System.Data.DataRow]` instances stringify as their full type name, i.e. "System.Data.DataRow"`. Did you mean to test `$row.'First/Only Design Number'`? Also, please clarify what the data type of this column is: when it doesn't contain strings, does it contain actual numbers, or just _string representations_ of numbers?

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($count.GetType() -ne "string"){
  if (-not $count -eq 0){...}
}
```

Comment: `.GetType()` stringifies as the _full_ type name, so it would be `"System.String"` for strings. However, you can use PowerShell's dedicated type operators: `$count -isnot [string]`

Answer (score 1):

You can try following

```
    foreach ($row in $table.Rows)
    {
        $firstDesignNumber = 0
        $fldVal = $row.'First/Only Design Number'
        if(-not [double]::TryParse($fldVal,[ref]$firstDesignNumber))
        {
            Continue
        }
        $FirstOnlyDesignNumbers += $firstDesignNumber
        $NextDesignNumbers += [int]$firstDesignNumber + [int]$row.'Application Count'
    }
```